# How to make a register an account in batch

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to make an account for a program I am making in batch? I mean, there is a way to log in with a specific username and password. But is there a way to create a username and password and make the batch file save it and remember it, so the user can login next time instead of register?

Hopefully you can understand. Thanks!

Comment: That depends entirely on what command line parameters the program that you are making takes. It sounds like what you're asking should be a feature of _your program_ and not a separate script. Having your users use a separate program in order to use your program is extremely poor design.

Comment: @SomethingDark: I don't see any reference to a _separate program_ in the question. Also, I don't understand how the register/login feature can be related to the command line parameters of the program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution create a username and password and make the Batch file save it in itself, as requested, so the user can login next time instead of register.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "username="
call :GetUserPass
if defined username goto login
echo You must register in order to use this program
set /P "username=Enter username: "
set /P "password=Enter password: "
echo set "username=%username%" >> "%~F0"
echo set "password=%password%" >> "%~F0"
goto begin

:badUserPass
echo Invalid username or password, try again
:login
set /P "user=Enter username: "
set /P "pass=Enter password: "
if "%user%" neq "%username%" goto badUserPass
if "%pass%" neq "%password%" goto badUserPass

:begin
echo/
echo Welcome to this program!
goto :EOF

:GetUserPass
```